# html5 canvas Clear permanently

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I've been creating a canvas were you can generate text and display in my canvas.

POST button and CLEAR button is working fine at First!

The next problem/bug I encounter is that when I type a new word and click POST,
the previous "cleared" letter will appear again.

```js
function updateTotal(){

if (document.getElementById('design3').checked) {
          var canvas2 = document.getElementById("displaycake_text");
              context = canvas2.getContext("2d");

          var $canvas2 = $("#displaycake_text");
          var canvasOffset = $canvas2.offset();
          var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
          var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
          var scrollX = $canvas2.scrollLeft();
          var scrollY = $canvas2.scrollTop();
          var startX;
          var startY;
          var texts = []; // an array to hold text objects
          var selectedText = -1;// this var will hold the index of the hit-selected text

        function draw() { // clear the canvas & redraw all texts
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
            for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) { var text = texts[i];
              context.fillText(text.text, text.x, text.y);  }
          }

        function textHittest(x, y, textIndex) { // test if x,y is inside the bounding box of texts[textIndex]
          var text = texts[textIndex];
            return (x >= text.x && x <= text.x + text.width && y >= text.y - text.height && y <= text.y);
            }

        function handleMouseDown(d) {
           d.preventDefault();
              startX = parseInt(d.clientX - offsetX);
              startY = parseInt(d.clientY - offsetY);
          
            for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
              if (textHittest(startX, startY, i)) {
                selectedText = i; }  }
          }

        function handleMouseUp(d) { // done dragging
          d.preventDefault();
            selectedText = -1;  }

        function handleMouseOut(d) { // also done dragging
            d.preventDefault();
            selectedText = -1;  }

        function handleMouseMove(d) {
          if (selectedText < 0) { return; }
          d.preventDefault();
            mouseX = parseInt(d.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(d.clientY - offsetY);

              var dx = mouseX - startX;
              var dy = mouseY - startY;
              startX = mouseX;
              startY = mouseY;
              var text = texts[selectedText];
              text.x += dx;
              text.y += dy;
              draw();     }
          
          $("#displaycake_text").mousedown(function (d) { handleMouseDown(d); }); // listen for mouse events
          $("#displaycake_text").mousemove(function (d) { handleMouseMove(d); });
          $("#displaycake_text").mouseup(function (d) {   handleMouseUp(d); });
          $("#displaycake_text").mouseout(function (d) {  handleMouseOut(d);  });
          $("#text_dedi").click(function () {
              var y = texts.length * 20 + 20; // calc the y coordinate for this text on the canvas
              var text = {  text: $("#dedi_text").val(),
                  x: 20,
              y: y
               };

            context.font = "30px Roboto";
            text.width = context.measureText(text.text).width;
            text.height = 16;
            text.color = "#ffffff";   
            texts.push(text); // put this new text in the texts array
            draw(); // redraw everything

          
          });
          
          //this is the code for CLEAR BUTTON
          document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);  texts = []; }, false);
        }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- PLS CLICK THE RADIO BUTTON FIRST THEN INSERT & POST -->
<br> <input type="radio" id="design3" name="design_3"  onchange="updateTotal()" />
<span class="radio-chosen"></span> Dedication
<h2> 
  <div class="disp_dedi off"> <input type="text" size="15" id="dedi_text" name="dedicationT" placeholder="Dedication"> 
<button id="text_dedi"> Post </button>  
  <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear" size="23" onchange="updateTotal()">  </div>


<canvas id="displaycake_text" height="200px" width="400px" style="border-color: #fff; border-style: solid;"> </canvas>
```

The text function is working fine as well the dragging (i just found the source of it)
But my CLEAR button is the problem, it still displays my deleted text.
Please, i hope anyone could help me. Thank you so much !

Comment: i see nowhere where the var texts is reset to an empty array, it could be part of the problem. Another thing, if you expect it to be reset because the var is declared at each `updateTotal()`, you have to take in account that jQuery `click` function adds the new handler function each time it is called. Because you never detach the function, multiple instances of the click can then be running. Maybe you should review your approach. I can elaborate an answer later if you still have trouble..

Comment: thanks for your response, this isn't considered for resetting my canvas? `document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);  }, false);`    I think I'm getting it but not really ... I'm not sure how to code it then...

Comment: it does, but IMO it either fills it again with the full array of all the previously entered texts, or rather fires multiple click bound functions and each writes the text that he has previously stored in memory. I'll try to post an answer whan i have time later.

Comment: wow thank you, really need help since I can't view on my console the error . And I don't have knowledge about this.  Is there somewhere in the JS code must be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kaddath said in the comments, the `texts` array is not being emptied when you click the clear button. Try clearing it when you clear the canvas:

```
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
          texts = [];
  }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So that's the only thing I'm missing. @@

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
function clear_canvas(canvas) {
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
}
```